# Trying to Rotate terrain

Tags: opengl, c++, terrain, terrain-rendering

I'm new to OpenGL and don't really know how to rotate a terrain. For my graphics class, I have a project I need to do that is making a tire using OpenGL and work that we done in class (my framework is one of the labs that we did that introduced us to heightmaps and terrains).

I have this tire tread terrain (see picture) that I made and how I'm going to make the tire is by making lots of these tire terrains and rotate them to make the tire shape. I'm sure there is better ways to accomplish this but my professor recommended I do this. So I was wondering how I can rotate it.

The code below is my code for the terrain that is shown in the picture.
Thank you in advance for the help!

```c
void TerrainScene()
{
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //gluLookAt(0,g.moveup,g.movedown,  0,0,0,  0,1,0);
    //gluLookAt(g.movedown-50,8,g.moveup,  g.movedown-50,-2,g.moveup-40,  0,1,0);
    gluLookAt(g.movedown-50,70,g.moveup,  g.movedown-50,-2,g.moveup-40,  0,1,0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, g.lightPosition);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glNormal3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    float x = -25.0;
    float z = -25.0;
    float inc = 0.2;
    glColor3f(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
        {
            float scale = 5.0;
            int tmp1 = (int)*(img[0].data + (i*img[0].width*3 + j*3));
            int tmp2 = (int)*(img[0].data + ((i+1)*img[0].width*3 + j*3));
            int tmp3 = (int)*(img[0].data + (i*img[0].width*3 + (j+1)*3));
            int tmp4 = (int)*(img[0].data + ((i+1)*img[0].width*3 + (j+1)*3));

            float e1 = -10.0 + ((float)tmp1 / 255.0) * scale;
            float e2 = -10.0 + ((float)tmp2 / 255.0) * scale;
            float e3 = -10.0 + ((float)tmp3 / 255.0) * scale;
            float e4 = -10.0 + ((float)tmp4 / 255.0) * scale;

            unsigned char rgb[3];
            getTerrainColor(i,j,1,rgb);
            glColor3ubv(rgb);
            Vec v1, v2, v3, norm;
            vecMake(x,      e2, z+inc, v1);
            vecMake(x+inc,  e4, z+inc, v2);
            vecMake(x,      e1, z,     v3);
            getTriangleNormal(v1,v2,v3,norm);
            glNormal3fv(norm);
            glVertex3f(x,     e2, z+inc);
            glVertex3f(x+inc, e4, z+inc);
            glVertex3f(x,     e1, z); 
            vecMake(x+inc,  e4, z+inc, v1);
            vecMake(x+inc,  e3, z,     v2);
            vecMake(x,      e1, z,     v3);
            getTriangleNormal(v1,v2,v3,norm);
            glNormal3fv(norm);

            glVertex3f(x+inc, e4, z+inc);
            glVertex3f(x+inc, e3, z); 
            glVertex3f(x,     e1, z); 
            x += inc;
        }
        x = -25.0f;
        z += inc;
    }   
    glEnd();
}
```

[image: image of my tire tread terrain]

Comment: How do you draw your terrain currently? What does the code look like? Also, I'm a little alarmed by your prof's suggested method, but I'll assume it makes sense for the particular lesson you're working on.

Comment: @DMGregory Hi, thank you for replying! I have edited my comment and added in my code for my terrain scene.

Comment: You could iterate pieces and use `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` around your outer loop. for every piece you would set `glRotate` and `glTranslate` and then draw it just like you do now.

Comment: @JonasBeck Thank you for replying! I tried adding `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` on my outer loop but it doesn't seem to do anything. maybe i'm not adding my `glRotate` and `glTranslate` in the right spot... Can you clarify what you mean by "for every piece"? Are you talking about the inner loop or certain parts in my inner loop?

Comment: @JonasBeck I've also never used `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` before so it could be that i'm not even doing that properly.

Comment: @Raúl you use them to specify a set of matrices for each of you tire pieces. `draw_wheel_and_bolts()
{
   long i;

   draw_wheel();
   for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      glPushMatrix();
         glRotatef(72.0*i,0.0,0.0,1.0);
         glTranslatef(3.0,0.0,0.0);
         draw_bolt();
      glPopMatrix();
   }
}` (https://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name6)

Comment: but remember that this is just one way to do this. you could also 'just' generate all vertices for a complete tire, use a geometry shader... many ways. but for old opengl3, using pop/push to manipulate the matrix stack is good to learn.